# Request to paginatinate

Tags: php, laravel, url, url-rewriting, pagination

I want to use paginate library but I have a problem. I'm using pagination.js and I want to use Ajax. This library required 2 parameters - pageNumber and pageSize and url will be:

```
test.json?pageNumber=2&pageSize=10
```

In Laravel I have a friendly url. Can I change overwrite to a few routes or maybe I can send request to friendly url, like this one?

```
localhost/ajax/pagination/1/10
```

Comment: If it's just an ajax request, why would it matter what the url looks like?

Comment: I don't know how I can solve it. So, library generate url like ""localhost/ajax/paginate?pageNumber=2&pageSize=10?" but Laravel "localhost/ajax/paginate/2/10". It's not this same url.